# WF: Get values from database to be used further in activity.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, sql-server-2012, workflow-foundation-4

Im creating a rule engine in WF in which I have to fetch the values from the database which will be used further for control flow inside the `activity.xaml`.

I'm using SQL server 2012 for storing the data

**TABLE NAME: Student**

**Column name: RollNo, Name**

In the this file I am calling the `activity.xaml`

```
public  class RuleSetInvoker
{
    public void PerformDesignerRules(ClaimFee claimfee)
    {
        var activity = new Activity1();
        ExecuteRules(activity, claimfee);
    }

    private void ExecuteRules(Activity activity,ClaimFee claimfee)
    {
        var input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        input.Add("ClaimFee", claimfee);
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity, input);
    }
```

// in **"input"** I would like to send my SQL data to the `activity.xaml`

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Add it to your post instead of posting it in the comments

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to get some data from an SQL database and then inject the retrieved data into a workflow.

In that case you are missing the code where you get the data from the database.
This is a good starter to learn that:
[Get data from SQL 2012 with C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiUSK5-sv4Q)

Once you have the data you insert it one field at a time into your input dictionary.  And then use your code to run the workflow

Comment: Thanks! But  I want to fetch data from database to custom activity in window workflow foundation

Comment: Well, that's what the answer above does.
Your question is not clear I suggest you re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

Build some service or API (HTTP) which will handle all your DB interactions (Create, Update, Get and Delete)

You can then call the service from your Workflow using built-in features like HTTPSend